# Saving raw CFA buffer to raw image

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, imaging, libraw, dcraw

I'm trying to save a raw sensor buffer as a raw file using PIL.
The buffer contains the CFA data (at 8-bit per pixel) and I'd like to save it as a raw CFA image that I'd be able to process later with and LibRaw (dcraw).

I've tried using PIL to save the image as a stream of bytes with .raw and .tiff suffix though it didn't work when I tried to load it.

When I load the image to numpy using imread, it seems that each pixel contains rgb (r=g=b) values.

```py
    def process_raw_string(input_image):

    with open(input_image, mode='rb') as file:
        file_content = file.read()

    treated_buffer=bytearray(file_content)

    f = open('data.raw', 'w+b')
    binary_format = bytearray(treated_buffer)
    f.write(binary_format)
    f.close()

    img = Image.frombuffer("P", (3328,496), treated_buffer, 'raw', "P", 0, 1)
    img.convert('L').save("rawgrayscale.tiff")
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using. Also, can you share a link to the file (using Google Drive, or Dropbox or somesuch) and information about its dimensions?

Comment: If your input is raw sensor data and the output is a raw data file, how and why is PIL involved? Surely there is no image realised in that process?

Comment: My input is the raw sensor buffer, so each byte represents one pixel from the CFA pattern (downsampled to 8-bit from 11-bit).
   `buffer=bytearray(file_content)`

    `img = Image.frombuffer("P", (3328,495), buffer, 'raw', "P", 0, 1)`
    `img.convert('L').save("rawgrayscale.png")`

Comment: Please share the file. Also, rather than putting code in comments where it is unformatted and difficult to read, please click `edit` under your question and add any code, or new information in there. StackOverflow folks don't like wading through comments to find the information ;-)